# MuleSoft/Java - Error: Unable to Resolve Method

Tags: java, mule, runtime-error

I've been working on a simple project with Mule. The goal is to take two numbers from the url and use those to create a range with which I then check to see if they are multiples of 3, 7, or both and print something out in turn. Flow code to follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
    <configuration doc:name="Configuration">
        <expression-language>
            <import class="sandbox.FindingMultiples" />
            <global-functions>
                def multiples(f,c)
                {
                     return sandbox.FindingMultiples.multiplesInRange(f,c);
                }
            </global-functions>
        </expression-language>
    </configuration>
    <flow name="multiples-implFlow">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log Start of Flow" message="multiples-implFlow: Starting flow..."/>
        <set-variable variableName="floor" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.floor]" doc:name="Set Floor Variable"/>
        <set-variable variableName="ceiling" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.ceiling]" doc:name="Set Ceiling Variable"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log Flow Variables" message="Floor: #[flowVars.floor] Ceiling: #[flowVars.ceiling]"/>
        <logger message="Starting transformation..." level="INFO" doc:name="Log Start of Transform"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    output: multiples((flowVars.floor), (flowVars.ceiling))
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="Completing transformation. Payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log Payload"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <logger message="Post Object to Json. Payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log Payload"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log End of Flow" message="multiples-implFlow: Completing Flow..."/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I use a  custom Java class I wrote to handle the logic:

```
package sandbox;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class FindingMultiples {

    public List<String> multiplesInRange(int floor, int ceiling)
    {
        int[] range = IntStream.rangeClosed(floor, ceiling).toArray();
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < range.length; i++)
        {
            if(range[i] % 3 == 0)
            {
                result.add(range[i] + " : " +  "ME");
                i++;
            }else if(range[i] % 7 == 0)
            {
                result.add(range[i] + " : " +  "MAY");
                i++;
            }else if(range[i] % 3 == 0 && range[i] % 7 == 0)
            {
                result.add(range[i] + " : " + "MAY and ME");
                i++;
            }else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

The package builds fine but when I  try to make a call with Postman I get the following error:

```
Message               : [Error: unable to resolve method: sandbox.FindingMultiples.multiplesInRange(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) [arglength=2]]
[Near : {... def multiples(f,c) ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1] (org.mule.mvel2.PropertyAccessException).
Payload               : {NullPayload}
Payload Type          : org.mule.transport.NullPayload
Element               : /multiples-implFlow/processors/5 @ sandbox:multiples-impl.xml:28 (Transform Message)
Element XML           : <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
                        <dw:set-payload>%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    output: multiples((flowVars.floor), (flowVars.ceiling))
}</dw:set-payload>
                        </dw:transform-message>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
[Error: unable to resolve method: sandbox.FindingMultiples.multiplesInRange(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) [arglength=2]]
[Near : {... def multiples(f,c) ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]
```

Along with the stack trace which I can provide in full upon request. I'm not sure how to resolve this error. Any help?

Comment: The two parameters of the method multiplesInRange are int. But in your  error, it says the method input are two strings. Have you checked that the parameters are int and not string when you use the method multiplesInRange. in other words, please check if the parameters (f,c) in  the method "multiples" are actually int and not string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the **`<import class=**/>`** statement in configuration is not able to import the required class properly.

I have had this issue which I worked around by writing import statement inside the Global function definition

You need to

- Import the java class which have the required function definition.
- Then create a new object and assign in to some variable
- Call the required method using "." dot operator with this variable.

Please try and update your configuration with below example snippet

```
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
        <expression-language>
            <global-functions>
                def multiples(f,c)
                {
                    import sandbox.FindingMultiples;
                    fm=new FindingMultiples();
                     return fm.multiplesInRange(f,c);
                }
            </global-functions>
        </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Hopeful this to be helpful to others as well.